# Need to send fax without much delay

Tags: fax, rightfax, winfax, popfax-api, interfax

I am new and I have no much knowledge about fax processing.

But, As We are using interfax service for sending fax that is working fine if we send one fax at a time there is not much delay/failure in this type of case, but our requirement is to send multiple faxes on a single number at a time (The numbers can be anything between 10 - 1000).

I have discussed with interfax support team and got below reply:

"It is important to note that they all go to the same number because of this: The InterFAX system will NOT send multiple faxes to the same number simultaneously. This is by design."

We are a shopping/food ordering service, and in our business model, once a customer makes any order, we send a fax to the business owner... so orders to a business can be multiple at a moment and thus multiple faxes will be sent by the system.so please let us know some fax services with fulfill our requirements without a delay of more than 1 minute for receiving a fax?

So, Please suggest me best fax API which can send multiple faxes at a time without much delay.

Answer (score 0):

normally, fax machines can process one call at a time. So if you were to send multiple faxes to that fax number, they will have to go through one at a time. This is true regardless of service provider as this is a limitation of the phone system.

Some of the more advanced fax machines can process multiple calls at the same time, you may want to check with the business owner if their fax machine can do the same - then ask the provider to send that number of calls at the same time to the fax.

Also, please make sure that the fax number you are sending to is always available and can always answer calls as soon as they come in.

Answer (score 0):

@Nilesh, it looks like you received a partial response from InterFAX. Here's the full one.

By default, the InterFAX system will stop itself from faxing more than one fax at a time to a single number. This is because, in general, people receiving faxes only have a single fax machine attached to their phone line.

But there are exceptions. For example, a call center with a multi-line fax server might be able to accept multiple concurrent faxes at a single fax number.

InterFAX supports such a situation. If you inform the support team that a fax number can receive multiple concurrent faxes, they can manually set the system to allow this. You will need to tell them how many faxes can be received at a time.

(Source: I am an InterFAX principal)